# Representation Theory of sl(5,C)

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

I want to develop a theory for the representation of sl(5,C).

I am asked to identify the Cartan Subalgebra of the algebra, which we can easily construct considering the matrices:

\begin{equation}
diag(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5): a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=0
\end{equation}
So we obtain 4 matrices of the form: ($\delta_i^i, -\delta_{i+1}^{1+1}$). The next step is to define a basis of the dual space h$^*$. So I deploy the isomorphic structure of the algebra and its dual (Because the killing form here is non-degenerate). I determine my dual basis as follows:
\begin{equation}
 H_1^*=\frac{4}{5}H_1+\frac{3}{5}H_2+\frac{2}{5}H_3+\frac{1}{5}H_4 \\
 H_2^*=\frac{3}{5}H_1+\frac{6}{5}H_2+\frac{4}{5}H_3+\frac{2}{5}H_4 \\
 H_3^*=\frac{2}{5}H_1+\frac{4}{5}H_2+\frac{6}{5}H_3+\frac{3}{5}H_4 \\
 H_4^*=\frac{1}{5}H_1+\frac{2}{5}H_2+\frac{3}{5}H_3+\frac{4}{5}H_4 \\
\end{equation}

I hope I have not made any calculation mistakes here. Then I am asked to define the roots of the system. We have all the information needed in the Cartan Matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
  2&-1& 0&0&\\
  -1&2& -1&0\\
  0&-1& 2&-1\\
  0&0& -1&2 \\
 \end{pmatrix}

And I am now asked to describe the roots in the basis $h^*$.

**My question is: I am supposed simply to evaluate $a_i(H_j^*) = a_i(\frac{4}{5}H_1+\frac{3}{5}H_2+\frac{2}{5}H_3+\frac{1}{5}H_4 )$ for instance and essentially redefine "cartan matrix" on the new basis which should be the inverse of the original one?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. To be honest with you, I have calculated the dual basis of sl(3) to determine its quadratic Casimir invariant. What makes me a bit confused here is the question, "Describe the roots in terms of the basis h*". My question is more like, Am I right in the last step I have in bold? If that is true, I mean the rest is straightforward. Thanks, though for your answer